# Add Command to Zsh History from Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, shell, zsh

I am scripting in Ruby and want to insert a command in the history for the Zshell that calls the Ruby script. I've tried this but it can't access the calling Zshell (I think)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
`zsh -c print -s what`
```

Any hints?

Comment: A child process can't modify its parent's environment (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/263022/2088135)

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, because there is a ``.zsh_history`` file but it's only loaded on startup; the current shell doesn't reference it all, instead just keeping its history in memory. If you open a new terminal and run something, it won't be added to any open shells. Unless there's some zsh function you can call to add something to the memory of all open shells (or at least a single open shell), you might be out of luck.

Comment: @piccolo I could run `fc -R` to reload a modified Zshell, but I think we're into the same problem again, right?

Comment: Oh hey, I did not know about that command. In that case, you can just append to ``.zsh_history``, if you're okay with manually running ``fc -R`` after the Ruby program exits. Maybe you could write some sort of zsh function that, after running a (specific?) Ruby program, it runs ``fc -R``.

Comment: @Piccolo that's great, but either way... no way to just put this nicely into the Ruby script. Oh well... Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer here, I'm glad to accept it.

Comment: I was just writing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can go about doing this is as follows:

Make a zsh function that calls `fc -R` after it finishes executing a certain command as follows:

```
function rb_yourprogram {
  ruby /path/to/your/program.rb && fc -R
}
```

In Ruby, append to the `~/.zsh_history` file:

```
File.open("~/.zsh_history", "a") do |f|
    f.puts "adds this line to history"
end
```

Now, you can call the program by typing `rb_yourprogram` into zsh, and after it finishes executing it will reload the history file and thus will have this new line of history (in addition to anything written into other zsh instances during the time since you opened the first shell).

You could also overload the `ruby` command in zsh so that it will always call `fc -R` after finishing execution:

```
function ruby {
  builtin ruby "$@" && fc -R
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do this here: https://gist.github.com/drosenstark/3557dfebd73857cb724a59a33bbbc1cc but this solution -- though amazing -- is a bit too clever for my taste. But there's no choice, I guess...

Comment: My god that's complicated. I was wanting to do this from a regular shell script.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat if you're doing this from a shell script, that should be as easy as just concatenating the line to the `~/.zsh_history` file and running `fc -R`, I think