# Unset http proxy in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

## Test.rb

```
Class Test

  %x( unset http_proxy )

  %x( unset https_proxy )

  %x( unset HTTP_PROXY )

  %x( unset HTTPS_PROXY )

  system ("echo $https_proxy") #result: http://10.10.10.10:8080

  system ("echo $https_proxy") #result: http://10.10.10.10:8080

  system ("echo $HTTPS_proxy") #result: http://10.10.10.10:8080 

  system ("echo $HTTP_proxy")  #result: http://10.10.10.10:8080

end
```

I cannot unset http_proxy in Ruby.
Please could help me for this issue!

Comment: Those commands all get executed in other processes and will not affect your current process nor your permanent environment.

Comment: If you're trying to modify your current program's environment, I think you can just delete that entry from ENV but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your execution of ruby is a process "child" of your computer.
Therefore you only get a COPY of the parent environement .

sources : http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-guide-environment-variables/
similar request in python : [Is it possible to change the Environment of a parent process in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263005/is-it-possible-to-change-the-environment-of-a-parent-process-in-python)