# Is it possible for 2 containers inside a Pod to share the same Environment Variables?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, windows-container

Is it possible for an InitContainer to change the environment variables of the application container when running inside the same Pod?

Note that I am looking for a detailed answer that describes the technical reasons why this is or isn't possible. Example: 'Current container technology supports environment variable isolation between containers and Pods cannot bypass that restriction by "grouping" containers in the same "environment variable space"'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is No, they can't.

You can try some hack something using [ShareProcessNamespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/) and [gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-environment-variables-of-another-process-in-unix) but for sure this is not correct solution for problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I would appreciate the long answer.

Comment: longer answer depends on what are you trying to achieve. I can imagine two options (please tell me if it's something else):
1. you are trying to simplify your deployment.yaml file to avoid repeating setting the same vars,
2. you are trying to use env as some form of inter process communication.

Just forget about 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263005/is-it-possible-to-change-the-environment-of-a-parent-process-in-python

regarding 1 - There is no syntax sugar for it in standard kubernetes.  but you can use some tempting solutions like helm or ksonnet.

Comment: Maciek long story short we have existing containers that we don't want to change.

Comment: Hi, is this still not possible? because I have a NodeJS app that is running basically two of itself inside of one pod but grabbing env variables from two different secrets

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to just change the variables like that. One of the possible workarounds is to use an `EmptyDir` volume shared between the `InitContainer` and the main container. You can store there a the variables using a file in `InitContainer` and load them in the main container using a some simple shell script.

Answer (score 1):

That exactly what we do with Vault on kubernetes, using the injector from https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/injector/annotations.

This will inject an init container.

Then, we use an `emptyDir` volume, the vault agent init container will create a file in it, then the running container will source it at start.