# How to read an arg from a volume in a kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I want to create a statefulset that runs an image that creates devices. I want each pod to create unique devices, so the first will do 1-20, and second 21-40 etc. The image takes in a flag that indicates what index to start at. I am struggling to implement this so that the flag is unique for each pod in the statefulset.

I tried to use an init container that creates a file on a volume, and puts the pod number on that file. this worked as expected. I can access this file from the main container as well. How do i pass the value in this file as an arg for my container? I have tried to directly access it in the args section as well as create an environment variable but neither work. Ideally something like this would work but does not:

```
env:
  - name: index 
    value: "cat ./pod/pod.toml"
args: ["--start-index","$(index)"]
```

Comment: What command do those `args:` get passed to; do you control the underlying program or image?  Are you using the absolutely most current Kubernetes version 1.28, and if so, do you mind using a beta feature?

Comment: [Is it possible for 2 containers inside a Pod to share the same Environment Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203731/is-it-possible-for-2-containers-inside-a-pod-to-share-the-same-environment-varia) is conceptually similar – you're precomputing some state in an init container, and want to pass it to the main container as an environment variable – but the short answer to that question is "no, you can't".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose the pod name as an environment variable via the [downward api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/):

```
env:
  - name: PODNAME
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.name
```

You can use this variable to calculate the index in a shell script, and then launch your service with the appropriate argument:

```
command:
- sh
- -c
- |
  podnumber=$(echo $PODNAME | cut -f2 -d-)
  startindex=$(( podnumber * 20 + 1 ))
  exec myserver --start-index $index
```

Pod 0 will run with `--start-index 1`, pod 1 will run with `--start-index 21`, etc.

Note that this does require overriding the `ENTRYPOINT` in your image (by setting `command` in the manifest) because you need to perform the calculations in a shell script. Whether this is easy or complex depends on the image that you're using and whether or not it has an extensive existing `ENTRYPOINT` script.