# Reading an environment variable set by a test in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: node.js, jenkins, protractor, jenkins-pipeline

Not found any reference to this particular question.

I am looking to find a way to achieve something like this in a Jenkins pipeline which runs our acceptance tests using Protractor and Cucumber.js:

```
            steps {
                container('selenium') {
                    script {
                        try {
                             {
                                //run tests
                            }
                        }
                        catch (err) {
                            if (env.testFailed == 'true') {
                                println "A test failure exists - build status updated to failure"
                                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                                error "Test(s) have failed"
                            } 
                            else {
                                println "No test failures exist - build status updated to success"
                                currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This would fail the build if the env var of testFailed is 'true'. The reason for this is we are encountering bugs with Protractor-Cucumber framework where if a failed test retries and passes the exit code of the stage is still 1.

So in the After hook of each test I am setting the env var using node.js to true if the Scenario status is failed:

```
  if (scenario.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
    process.env.testFailed = 'true';
  }
  if (scenario.result.status === Status.PASSED) {
    process.env.testFailed = 'false';
  }
```

The problem I have found is that the Jenkins pipeline fails to read the env var value in the code block of the catch section. It is always null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change the Environment of a parent process in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263005/is-it-possible-to-change-the-environment-of-a-parent-process-in-python)

Comment: Potentially, I think the idea of writing to a file might be my best bet

Answer (score 2):

1) change the After hook to write the true/false flag to a file in sync.

2) read the file in catch block

```
catch(err) {
   testFailed = sh(script:'cat result.flag.txt', returnStdout: true).trim()
   if(testFailed == 'true') {
      ...
   }
```

}

Another option if there is total/passed/failed case number in output of npm test

```
lines = []

try {
   lines = sh(script:'npm test', returnStdout: true).readLines();    
}
catch(err) {
   size = lines.size()

   // parse the last 20 lines to extract fail/pass/total number
   for(int i=size-20;i<size;i++) {
      line[i]
   } 
}
```

Comment: Very nice idea, will try this out

Comment: So got an additional issue. Our tests run in parallel! So this file is often being overridden. So a test will fail and the file updates. But then another test will pass and overwrite the value and the pipeline will, wrongly, pass as a result! Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: In the After hook, only when test fail to write the flag file, test pass won't do that. But you mentioned failed test will be retried, so I don't think mark the test result in After hook is a good option, I think parse the total/passed/failed cases number from the output of `npm test` in the catch is better.

Answer (score 1):

**WHY IT DOESN'T WORK NOW?**

I see that you're running your tests in a container. When you set an environment variable, it's reflected on the scope of your container not the Jenkins master server

**WHAT YOU COULD TRY TO DO**

This actually depends on how you run the tests, but this should be an option

```
// run tests here

// you should have a variable for your container
def exit_code = sh(script: "sudo docker inspect ${container.id} --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'", returnStdout: true)

sh "exit ${exit_code}"
```

This actually also depends how you start the tests inside the container,
So if you update your answer with this information I could help you

Comment: Thanks Sergey, yong's answer has worked for me. So will use that I think. This is great info though. We start the tests via an NPM script command.