# Setting Environment Variables in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to set an environment variable from a Mathematica notebook.

```
Environment["VARIABLE"]
```

gives the value of the variable. But is it possible to set a variable, too?

Answer (score 4):

There's no built in function (to my knowledge), but you can just use

```
Run["set VAR=VALUE"]
```

or

```
!set VAR=VALUE
```

instead.

Edit: You'll want to see the documentation for the [Run](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Run.html) and [RunThrough](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RunThrough.html) commands.

Comment: "set" does not seem to work, but "export" does (I'm using bash on Mac OS X).

:~ cls$ export VAR=VALUE
:~ cls$ echo $VAR
VALUE

However, it does not work from Mathematica.

In[15]:= Run["export VAR=VALUE"]

Out[15]= 0

In[16]:= Environment["VAR"]


Out[16]= $Failed

Even if I set the variable from the command line, it cannot be retrieved with Environment[].

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables set up with [Run](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Run.html) or [RunThrough](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RunThrough.html) will not affect the *Mathematica* kernel itself but will only be visible to processes launched within the same `Run` or `RunThrough` command.

If the environment variable should be visible to the *Mathematica* kernel process, the gdb based hack described in the accepted answer to [Is there a way to change another process's environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables) can be used under Mac OS X:

```
SetEnvironment[var_String, value_String] := Module[{valueEscaped, cmd},
    valueEscaped = StringTake[ToString[CForm[value]], {2, -2}];
    cmd = "call (int) putenv (\"" <> var <> "=" <> valueEscaped <> "\")";
    Put[OutputForm[cmd], "!gdb -n \"" <> First[$CommandLine] <> "\" " <> ToString[$ProcessID ]]
]
```

The *Mathematica* [Put](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Put.html) command is used to launch gdb and have it attach itself to the *Mathematica* kernel process. The gdb command `call (int) putenv ("var=value")` is then sent to gdb on stdin to set up the environment variable with [putenv](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/putenv.3.html).

Caveat: Under Mac OS X gdb is only available if the [Xcode developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/) are installed.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are going to do this before you try to run an external command right?
Why not instead just run "VARNAME=value; your_original_external_command"
that will temporarily set the evn variable.