# Changing environment variable of a running process

Tags: linux, bash, export, environment

I have a script that exports an environment variable and starts some subscripts.

```
export LOGLEVEL="1"
/home/myuser/bin/myscript1.sh
/home/myuser/bin/myscript2.sh
```

`LOGLEVEL` is available to the processes started from the subscripts. How can I change the environment variable `LOGLEVEL`?

I have tried to set the variable with `export LOGLEVEL="5"` but that`s not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change another process's environment variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables)

Comment: Where do you want the LOGLEVEL changed and for what process - as you state it has changed for the two myscript processes.

Comment: @Mark: It doesn't matter if LOGLEVEL is changed for the processes of both subscripts, or if I can change it for individual processes. Essentially I'm looking for any working way talking to a process, that it should print more information into it's logfile.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer - then you need to show us how you use LOGLEVEL in the scripts

Comment: @Mark: Sorry that I wasn't accurate enough, but LOGLEVEL is only exported in the script, it is used from the processes through `getenv()`.

Comment: So changing it as you have done affects what the scripts print as they use getenv - what exactly do you want?

Comment: @Mark: The script starts some processes after system has started. The processes are printing some information into their logfiles depending on the environment variable LOGLEVEL. Now I want to change the behavior of the processes without restarting them.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: I just added a suggestion to my answer below.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In general, you can only influence a process's environment variables at the time the process starts up.  If you need to communicate a change to a running process, the environment isn't the right tool.

However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables) has some answers that suggest ways to overcome this limitation.

Edited to add in light of discussion in the question's comments:  A fairly good way of communicating occasionally changing setup to a running process is to designate a configuration file where the LOGLEVEL value is set, send a SIGHUP to the process, and have the process reread the configuration file upon receipt of SIGHUP.

Comment: Thank you for the link and the clue how to manage this in the right way – I have read more about SIGHUP and found on Wikipedia: _Daemon programs sometimes use SIGHUP as a signal to restart themselves, the most common reason for this being to re-read a configuration file which has been changed_