# How to stop GStreamer DEBUG logs

Tags: gstreamer

I am enabling **GST_DEBUG = 7** and then starting a media application, so I keep on getting the logs which I have set as **"GST_DEBUG_FILE":"/var/log/gst-log"**.

Q. If I close the media application I stop getting the logs(*which is fine*), but is there any way to stop the GST_DEBUG logs using CLI ?

Please correct me if my thought process is not in right direction, I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to change the value of GST_DEBUG environment variable when GStreamer process is running. If so, in general you can't do that. There are however some ways to overcome that. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589221/changing-environment-variable-of-a-running-process) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables) question.