# How to modify a LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable?

Tags: linux, gtk3, glib, path-variables

I have Ubuntu 16.04, and installing gtk+3.22.20, a version of GLIB >= 2.49.4 is needed. When running the 'configure' script, it says it detects that GLIB is 2.48.2. However, 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returns 2.52.3 since I installed that version.

They suggest to:

> "remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is required on your system."

How to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing environment variable of a running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589221/changing-environment-variable-of-a-running-process)

Comment: @DavidNathan it is not. I think he's asking about during configure, so before the process starts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the environmental variable LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13428910/608639), [Why changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH has no effect in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47682750/608639), [Where is LD_LIBRARY_PATH? how do I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168340), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to your ~/.bashrc:

`echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your/custom/path/" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: .bashrc I see! I guess I have to figure out the path of glib 2.52.3 
Thank you Ivan