# How to set dir as anvironment directory?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, shared-libraries

I am trying to load shared library, but I dont have its .so file in directory loader look for, So I want to set a environment dir.

```
$ ls # (current dir is bindir)
foo.c foo.h libfoo.so exe
$ path_to_dir=/home/user/bindir
$ $path_to_dir ./exe "bla bla"
bash: /home/user/bindir: Is a directory
```

This may be trivial, But i do not usually run program with modified environment variables, so how to set it?

If I tried to `$ export path_to_dir`, and run it:

```
$ ./exe "bla bla"
./_exe: error while loading shared libraries: libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So how to modify the environment variable of my dir?

EDIT:
according to this tutorial: [youtube library tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbHmin2Wtmc), the linker cannot see the library (`libfoo.so`, in my case) file, becuase it does not search my current dirctory. The standard libraries `ld` uses, I get by this:

```
$ld --verbose | grep -i search_dir | awk '{print $1}' RS=';'
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib")
```

So the the the relation between the variable `$path_to_dir` and those above is, that I want to make my directory visible to `ld` by making the `$path_to_dir` as environment variable (also tried `export`, but as you see - to no avail). So how to make visible my dir to `ld` in order to "see" my library and link it with the position-independet program?

Comment: How is `path_to_dir` variable related to finding the `.so` file?

Comment: @KamilCuk the program loader is looking for new libreries and cannot find mine. The standard dirs, the loader looks are e.g. `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, etc`. So I want to modify the environment, so loader can See my library and use it.

Comment: @KamilCuk see my edits

Comment: Cool, but why did you name the variable `path_to_dir`? Why did you think that a variable with that particular name would affect linker? Read [man ld-linux](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify a LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175203/how-to-modify-a-ld-library-path-environment-variable)