# CMake doesn't see environment variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I am new with CMake, and am using Visual Studio Code with SSH to Linux. In my ~/.bashrc file I have an environment variable exported to a directory path. I have checked it with PRINTENV, and the path is correct. In CMake however the path is undefined. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
    IF(DEFINED ENV{ALPHA_DIR})
        SET(ALPHA_DIR $ENV{ALPHA_DIR})
    ELSEIF(NOT DEFINED ALPHA_DIR OR ALPHA_DIR STREQUAL "NOT-SET")
        SET(ALPHA_DIR "NOT-SET" CACHE PATH "ALPHA_DIR directory")
        MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "** Please add the variable 'ALPHA_DIR'")
    ENDIF()
```

with the output generated:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (MESSAGE): ** Please add the variable 'ALPHA_DIR'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What happens when your CMake runs? Does it print `** Please add the variable 'ALPHA_DIR'`? Or is there an error?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I get "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:37 (MESSAGE):  ** Please add the variable 'ALPHA_DIR'"

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? And please show the commands you use to call CMake. Are you running from the command line? Or from within VS Code?

Comment: CMake version is 3.14.5. It's called from within VS Code. It's just "cmake <path-to-source>"

Comment: You may need to set the environment variable in your `launch.json` config file. See this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48609350/3987854).