# can't set/access value of NODE_ENV environment variable

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, development-environment, dotenv

I currently have a node.js application where I have a `require('dotenv').config();` line that I only want to run when the application is in development, and not production mode.

To achieve this, I want to set a NODE_ENV environment variable to 'development' locally (and set to 'production' when on AWS), and I'll have an set of conditional statements like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
require('dotenv').config();
}
```

I cannot set this NODE_ENV variable in my .env file, as then accessing that would require the `require('dotenv').config();` line which will only run depending on whether the if statement evaluates to true. I have tried to set the value of NODE_ENV through `set NODE_ENV=development` in the terminal in vscode, but it didn't work so I had to do it on command prompt, where it did work (confirmed by typing the command set and seeing NODE_ENV=development), but now when I try to access it through process.env.NODE_ENV, its value is undefined - anyone know the correct procedures to set/access NODE_ENV?

Comment: How did you start you node application in the terminal? e.g. `NODE_ENV=developement node your_script.js`

Comment: I use vscode as an IDE and I usually just debug to start the application - I don't run anything in the terminal to start the application

Comment: do I need to use NODE_ENV in some command?

Comment: If you launch your node application trough the debugging section in VS code then you need to setup you env variables in the `launch.json` file. Check the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables).
An example on how to set them is also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58867939/2362668

Answer (score 0):

After setting your environment variable in Windows OS you need to restart your PC to make an effect in the env variable value.

then retrieve the value in node.js using `app.get('NODE_ENV')` or `process.env.NODE_ENV`