# How to run project with arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs

I create an project with Typescript and NestJS, but i must run this project in vscode(from launch.json or terminal or something else) with this arguments from process.env:

```
"MYSQL_HOST":"x", 
"MYSQL_PORT":"x", 
"MYSQL_USERNAME":"x", 
"MYSQL_PASSWORD":"x", 
"MYSQL_DATABASE":"x", 
"NODE_ENV":"x"
```

can somebody tell me in which way i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add env variables to `.env` and import it using EasyconfigModule

```
import  { Module }  from  '@nestjs/common';
import { EasyconfigModule } from  'nestjs-easyconfig';

@Module({
 imports:  [EasyconfigModule.register({path: './config/.env'})],
})
export  class  AppModule  {}
```

Comment: nope, i do not want to do this in this way, i want to run this from terminal/cmd

Comment: @comodo assuming its for development you can set in in launch.json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595446/is-there-any-way-to-set-environment-variables-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run NestJS from the terminal/cmd you can set environment variables using the npm package [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and then construct your command like this:

```
cross-env MYSQL_HOST=localhost MYSQL_PORT=1234 [and so on] nest start
```

The cross-env package isn't strictly necessary, it just makes it easier to have your command work across different environments. That way, you wont have to create separate commands for i.e. Windows and Linux.

Alternatively, you can use launch.json by setting up your variables in the `env`-property:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        ...
        "env": {
            "MYSQL_HOST": "localhost",
            "MYSQL_PORT": 1234
        }
    }
]
```