# Toggle Test Coverage with os.Getenv

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, visual-studio-code

I'm making a simple test, and test using `Go: Toggle Test Coverage In Current Package` in `Visual Studio Code` like this
[image: vscode]

In my code is using `os.Getenv` to read a variable from my own env.
It get `FAIL` when using `os.Getenv`, but `SUCCESS` when hardcoded

How to get `SUCCESS` even get data from `env` using `Go: Toggle Test Coverage In Current Package`?

Here is my code:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func MyFunc() ([]MyStruct, error) {
    str := os.Getenv("MyStruct")  // Fail 
    // str := `[{"name": "one"}, {"name": "two"}]` // Success

    var myData []MyStruct
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &myData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return myData, nil
}
```

My test code:

```golang
func TestMyFunc(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        want    []MyStruct
        wantErr error
    }{
        {
            name: "success",
            want: []MyStruct{
                {
                    Name: "one",
                },
                {
                    Name: "two",
                },
            },
            wantErr: nil,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got, err := MyFunc()
            assert.Equal(t, err, tt.wantErr)
            assert.Equal(t, got, tt.want)
        })
    }
}
```

My env:

```sh
export MyStruct='[{"name": "one"}, {"name": "two"}]'
```

Using

Comment: this should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595446/is-there-any-way-to-set-environment-variables-in-visual-studio-code/48609350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
Just add this code to test code:

```golang
strEnv := `[{"name": "one"}, {"name": "two"}]`
err := os.Setenv("MyStruct", strEnv)
if err != nil {
    return
}
```