# unable to set CGO_ENABLED=1

Tags: go

So I am trying to run my code from visual studio code using the command

```
go run -race .
```

This is giving me the error:

**go: -race requires cgo; enable cgo by setting CGO_ENABLED=1**

I tried setting it by using the command but nothing happens:

```
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

Can somebody tell me how to set the CGO_ENABLED env variable to 1 because I am not able to do it

Comment: How exactly have you done this? In a batch script? Are you sure that you set the env var correctly? You are on Windows, right?

Comment: not a batch script.I am running the command directly in visual studio terminal

Comment: So are you settings CGO_ENABLED=1 first, then after that go run the program? That should do the trick.

Comment: yes.I run the set CGO_ENABLED=1 command after which run the go run -race . which is giving me the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a batch script `run.bat` to run your code:

```
set CGO_ENABLED=1
go run -race .
```

To accomplish this in Visual Studio Code, you can modify the environment variables via a launch script, see this question:

[Is there any way to set environment variables in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595446/is-there-any-way-to-set-environment-variables-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
go env -w CGO_ENABLED=1
```

---

But if you don't have a **C compiler** installed on your machine, you will get another error message after setting this variable and trying to use `go run -race .`:

> cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%

If so, here are VS Code's instructions on how to install it

- *Windows:* https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
- *Linux:* https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux

Comment: The Linux instruction add the GDB debugger installation which is not needed (for the OP), so this is enough:
sudo apt-get install build-essential