# Undefined problems usin the package miekg/PKCS11 in Golang

Tags: go, pkcs#11

I'm trying to use this package using Golang but doesn't matter what I do I always receive the same Undefined errors in New, Mechanism and NewMechanism.
I've already checked the environment variables and all of them are correct.

Someone knows how can I solve this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/miekg/pkcs11"
)

func main() {

    p := pkcs11.New("/user/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.dll")
    err := p.Initialize()
    if err != nil {


        panic(err)
    }

    defer p.Destroy()
    defer p.Finalize()

    slots, err := p.GetSlotList(true)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    session, err := p.OpenSession(slots[0], pkcs11.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION|pkcs11.CKF_RW_SESSION)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer p.CloseSession(session)

    err = p.Login(session, pkcs11.CKU_USER, "1234")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer p.Logout(session)

    p.DigestInit(session, []*pkcs11.Mechanism{pkcs11.NewMechanism(pkcs11.CKM_SHA_1, nil)})
    hash, err := p.Digest(session, []byte("this is a string"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, d := range hash {
        fmt.Printf("%x", d)
    }
    fmt.Println()

}
```

RESULT:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/miekg/pkcs11
go: downloading github.com/miekg/pkcs11 v1.1.1
go: found github.com/miekg/pkcs11 in github.com/miekg/pkcs11 v1.1.1
# play
./prog.go:11:14: undefined: pkcs11.New
./prog.go:37:34: undefined: pkcs11.Mechanism
./prog.go:37:51: undefined: pkcs11.NewMechanism

Go build failed.
```

Comment: Show exact build command.

Comment: `github.com/miekg/pkcs11` at @v1.1.1 [definitely contains `New`](https://github.com/miekg/pkcs11/blob/f3481918a208bd212aa995a41f92d786eb418a7d/pkcs11.go#L786) so the problem must not be with the package itself. I'm with Volker.

Answer (score 0):

simply enable CGO flag:

`CGO_ENABLED=1 go build main`

in windows you can use cgo by installing mingw [docs](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#windows), I recommend [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) package

Comment: I did what you said and didn't work. I downloaded and installed the msys2 package in my windows and I tried to Enable the CGO in the VSCode but the command was not recognized.

Comment: @VictorFM look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673557/unable-to-set-cgo-enabled-1

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem. But now a new problem appeared XD