# Trying to start a root session from VSCode by setting it up with cmd commands

Tags: windows, python, batch-file, cmd, import

I'm a bit lost. I can't seem to be able to import ROOT (from CERN) from the Python files in VSCode. I'm able to do it from the CMD but not from a Python script.

In CMD, it's the following procedure to make it work:

```
-->Admin>C:/path/to/root/bin/thisroot.bat
-->Admin>echo %ROOTSYS%
C:/path/to/root
-->Admin>python
>>>import ROOT
>>>
```

Now this is good because I can access ROOT from Python and everything is fine. I want to do this procedure automatically at the beginning of my Python script and I thought about giving the CMD commands from the Python file and I tried this:

```
import subprocess
import os

command_root_bat = 'C:/Users/Admin/root_v6.30.02/bin/thisroot.bat'
subprocess.run(command_root_bat, shell=True)
command_root_sys = 'echo %ROOTSYS%'
result = subprocess.run(command_root_sys, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, env=os.environ)
if result.returncode == 0:
    print(f"Command executed successfully. Output: {result.stdout}")
else:
    print(f"Error executing command. Error message: {result.stderr}")
```

When I run this, I get %ROOTSYS% as an output instead of the path like the correct version in CMD. Also, the import ROOT doesn't work this time. I feel like this is way too complicated to simply import ROOT for Python but I'm not finding anything and the documentation of ROOT for Windows is really not that great.

Any help would be appreciated, whether it's for solving this issue with the CMD commands or finding a new simple way to import ROOT in Python using a script from VSCode.

P.S. I'm not even sure this is the correct place to ask this question.

Comment: If you have a problem with something in `C:\Users\Admin\root_v6.30.02\bin\thisroot.bat`, then we need to see the content of that file!

Answer (score 0):

For environment variables like `%ROOTSYS%`, it may be easier to start CMD, launch `thisroot.bat` to initialize, then run `code` from the same window to launch VS Code and inherit the environment.

Using `subprocess.run()` will only initialize cmd within the scope of that single subprocess, and won't affect the parent python shell.

Depending on what order you need things in, you could rewrite the `.bat` steps in python to use when launching from VS Code with stuff like `os.environ["ROOTSYS"] = "C:/path/to/root"`.

Check out [Is there any way to set environment variables in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595446/) for more VS-style examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to change the ROOTSYS into my path `os.environ["ROOTSYS"] = "C:/path/to/root"`. The problem now is that the Kernel is crashing before being able to import ROOT but I think this is a separate issue.