# Load dependent .so from other shared library via JNI

Tags: linux, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, dynamic-loading, java.library.path

I want to call some function of liba.so from other libb.so.
libb.so is dynamic so library that implement native method which i have loaded using System.loadLibrary("b") inside JNI. first i have set complete path for both of .so inside jni using java.library.path but when i run my java programs , while loading shared library libb.so,
it gives below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: x/y/z/libb.so: liba.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
```

1. first i have linked shared library liba.so with other shared library libb.so during compilation using

   g++ -shared -o libb.so -fPIC b.cc -L/x/y/z -la

   (say complete path of liba.so is /x/y/z)
2. In JNI, i have set java.library.path pragmatically that contains complete path of liba.so, libb.so and then  i used to load JNI native library libb.so as

(say complete path of libb.so is a/b/c and 
complete path of liba.so is x/y/z.)

```
String libpath = "x/y/z" + "a/b/c";
System.setProperty( "java.library.path", libpath);
    try {
        Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
        fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
        fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
       }
    catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
```

// here i am able to print/fetch correct java.library.path. (path of both shared library saved correctly into java.library.path)

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("b");
}
```

when my java programs load this dynamic library of static block , it gives below error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: x/y/z/liba.so: libb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Note: When i set path of liba.so in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, this work fine without any error. but i don't want to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in SHELL. just i want to set java.library.path or LD_LIBRARY_PATH in program itself.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-023/

Comment: @Oo.oO, when i set path of liba.so in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then its works. but when i try to set depended library( liba.so) path in java.library.path through program, it gives error.

Comment: it will not work with java.library.path. once inside liba.so you depend on system.

Comment: @Oo.oO, even when i set path of liba.so in LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside program, it won't work. i think you can't change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting for a running process inside program once its already started. I searched various discussion, I am not able to find a way to overcome above error without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in SHELL before program starts.

Comment: take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-018

Comment: yes, that's what i have done, but point is you have to always set path of other library that you open in native library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This other dependent library path (liba.so ) can't be set at runtime once JVM has started.

Comment: you can also use -rpath while building liba.so and pointing to libb.so. at some point, somehow, you have to tell liba.so how to find libb.so :(

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you control the location of the shared objects `liba.so` and `libb.so`, compile your `libb.so` shared object with an [embedded `RPATH` set so that it can locate `liba.so`](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath).

If the two shared objects are located in the shame directory, this would work:

```
g++ -shared -o libb.so -fPIC b.cc -L/x/y/z -la -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/.'
```

(`$ORIGIN` by itself would work, but I like to use `$ORIGIN/.` to clearly show the result is a directory.  If you have the common `bin` and `lib` directory tree, always using `$ORIGIN/../lib` for both executables and shared object is also IMO a good idea.)

The `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/.` will set an `RPATH` in the `libb.so` shared object so that the runtime linker searches the same directory `libb.so` is located in for `liba.so`.

Answer (score 1):

Loading a dependent library from a native library is a purely OS action so it's outside of Java control. Unfortunately, you cannot fix this issue with Java-provided instruments.

As you noted, in Linux library search path can be set by the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, but it's not possible to modify the environment variable of the already running JVM process (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589221/changing-environment-variable-of-a-running-process) with a suggestion for a [hack using gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-environment-variables-of-another-process-in-unix) not really usable for the non-debug case).

The issue you described is filed as a JDK bug for Windows https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213772 with a comment *there is really nothing we can do*.

However, there should be a simple solution for your case:

Load the dependent library **liba.so** explicitly prior to loading **libb.so**:

```java
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("a");
        System.loadLibrary("b");
    }
```

In the case of multiple dependent libraries and deeper dependency hierarchy levels, load all the dependent libraries manually one by one in reverse order.