# libusb will not link correctly when cross-compiling Rust hidapi-rs library to Android

Tags: android, rust, hid, libusb, hidapi

I am writing an app for android that interfaces with HID devices. The backend is written in Rust using [hidapi-rs](https://github.com/ruabmbua/hidapi-rs) and uses Jetpack Compose for the UI. I compile my rust library into a shared library using [rust-android-gradle](https://github.com/mozilla/rust-android-gradle) and can successfully load the library and call from it in the app if I comment out all of the HID-related stuff, but as soon as I include the HID-realated stuff, my app crashes as soon as the library is loaded using `System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary")`. It returns a runtime error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.me.myapp, PID: 24129
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "libusb_init" referenced by "libMyLibrary.so"...
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)
        at com.me.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:34)
```

I am at a loss and have been trying to figure out how to fix this for four days.

I have tried a few different approaches:
**1.**
I tried compiling `libusb` for Android according to [their instructions](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/android) and manually moving the `.so` files to my `libs` folder in my project. I then tried to load both libraries with

```
System.loadLibrary("usb1.0")
System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary")
```

`libusb1.0.so` loads successfully, but again, the app crashes when `libMyLibrary.so` is loaded.

**2.**
I attempted using a different Rust HID library, [hidapi-rusb](https://github.com/joshieDo/hidapi-rs), which is a drop in replacement that builds off of [rusb](https://github.com/a1ien/rusb) instead of libusb. This did not solve the problem either.

**3.**
Finally, I went back to `hidapi-rs` and attempted to build it locally to use with my Rust library. This did not fix the issue either.

I also made sure to add the correct permissions to my `AndroidManifest.xml` file according to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host) by adding

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />
```

I want to try to link a libusb library to my Rust library when I build, but I do not know how and there are not many resources to do so.

This app has been released successfully on MacOS using `hidapi-rs`, but Android does not want to cooperate. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373254/load-dependent-so-from-other-shared-library-via-jni#58842312

Comment: @Markus That sounds like the same problem, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that same thing with cargo.