# How to call func everytime when we use var

Tags: go, environment-variables

How I can rewrite the below code so that whenever I use the var `CsvVersion` every time it calls the func and gives me the latest value?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var (
    DefaultValMap = map[string]string{
        "CSV_VERSION": "v1",
    }

    CsvVersion = GetEnvOrDefault("CSV_VERSION")
)

func GetEnvOrDefault(env string) string {
    if val := os.Getenv(env); val != "" {
        return val
    }

    return DefaultValMap[env]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(CsvVersion)
    os.Setenv("CSV_VERSION", "v2")
    fmt.Println(CsvVersion)
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("CSV_VERSION"))
}
```

Actual output

```
$ go build 1.go && ./1 
v1
v1
v2
```

The output should be like this

```
$ go build 1.go && ./1 
v1
v2
v2
```

Comment: Unrelated but go build works best without filename arguments.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to do this exact thing in Go.  Go, very much by design, avoids "magic" things like this.  Instead, don't use a variable, use a function:

```golang
func CsvVersion() string {
    return GetEnvOrDefault("CSV_VERSION")
}
```

However note: It's not (generally) possible to change environment variables after a program starts (except within the program itself, which has very limited utility), so checking an env variable on every use is usually just wasted effort. Read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589221/changing-environment-variable-of-a-running-process).