# How can I permanently export a variable in Linux?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, redhat

I am running [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 6, and I have exported an environment variable like this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

That variable is lost when the terminal is closed. How do I permanently add this so that this variable value always exists with a particular user?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

You can add it to your shell configuration file, e.g., *$HOME/.bashrc* or more globally in */etc/environment*.

After adding these lines, the changes won't reflect instantly in GUI-based systems. You have to exit the terminal or create a new one and on the server, log out the session and log in to reflect these changes.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. How can I make changes take effect without restart ? *(I'm Linux newbie)*

Comment: @mini-me - ~/bashrc is pulled each time you open a shell. To load it explicitly, use `source` e.g. - `> source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @kostja For all **new** shells ? If I have eclipse running before I change those env variables and I want eclipse to have changed vars, do I have to restart eclipse ?

Comment: @mini-me: the environment of a process is usually set by the caller and changed from within the process. Changing env from outside a running process is unusual and not doable with `export`, but [try with a debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables)

Comment: @mini-me - it depends on the file. As I said before, ** ~/.bashrc is pulled automatically each time you open a shell** - so you dont have to `source` the `.bashrc` explicitly, except you want to pull changes into an already open shell. You will have to `source` changes in **all** other configuration files on each change for **every** shell if you dont want to restart.

Comment: Where should I put that line?! bottom of page?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde: It usually doesn't matter. Files are parsed from top to bottom, so if a var definition depends on another, they should be ordered accordingly. So yes the end of the file is fine.

Comment: just note `Shell config files such as ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, and ~/.bash_login are often suggested for setting environment variables. While this may work on Bash shells for programs started from the shell, variables set in those files are not available by default to programs started from the graphical environment in a desktop session.` from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 187):

You have to edit three files to set a permanent environment variable as follow:

- #### ~/.bashrc

  When you open any terminal window this file will be run. Therefore, if you wish to have a permanent environment variable in all of your terminal windows you have to add the following line at the end of this file:

  ```
  export DISPLAY=0
  ```
- #### ~/.profile

  Same as **bashrc** you have to put the mentioned command line at the end of this file to have your environment variable in every login of your OS.
- #### /etc/environment

  If you want your environment variable in every window or application (not just terminal window) you have to edit this file. Add the following command at the end of this file:

  ```
  DISPLAY=0
  ```

  Note that in this file you do not have to write *export* command

Normally you have to restart your computer to apply these changes. But you can apply changes in **bashrc** and **profile** by these commands:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.profile
```

But for */etc/environment* you have no choice but restarting (as far as I know)

## A Simple Solution

I've written a simple script for these procedures to do all those work. You just have to set the name and value of your environment variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter variable name: "
read variable_name
echo "Enter variable value: "
read variable_value
echo "adding " $variable_name " to environment variables: " $variable_value
echo "export "$variable_name"="$variable_value>>~/.bashrc
echo $variable_name"="$variable_value>>~/.profile
echo $variable_name"="$variable_value>>/etc/environment
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.profile
echo "do you want to restart your computer to apply changes in /etc/environment file? yes(y)no(n)"
read restart
case $restart in
    y) sudo shutdown -r 0;;
    n) echo "don't forget to restart your computer manually";;
esac
exit
```

Save these lines in a shfile then [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-run-from-termina) and just run it!

Comment: The script worked very well. I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I just pasted the content above in a blank file, named it **insert_var.sh**, then `chmod -x insert_var.sh`, then `bash insert_var.sh`. Thanks.

Comment: I opened a Terminal Window in Ubuntu and enter export MY_VAR=1. Where will this Variable MY_VAR stored ?

Comment: Your variable `MY_VAR` will only be part of the current shell that you are working on. If you close the shell, the variable will be inaccessible.

Comment: I tested the approach with just the `/etc/environment` file on CentOS 8 and I didn't need to restart I just needed to exit (log out) the terminal or create a new one (log in).

Answer (score 37):

On [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) systems, use the following locations:

1. System-wide persistent variables in the format of `JAVA_PATH=/usr/local/java` store in

   ```
   /etc/environment
   ```
2. System-wide persistent variables that reference variables such as
   `export PATH="$JAVA_PATH:$PATH"` store in

   ```
   /etc/.bashrc
   ```
3. User-specific persistent variables in the format of `PATH  DEFAULT=/usr/bin:usr/local/bin` store in

   ```
   ~/.pam_environment
   ```

For more details on #2, check this
[Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78856/referencing-environment-variables-in-etc-environment/385036#385036).

NOTE:  #3 is the Ubuntu recommendation, but it may have security concerns in the real world.

Answer (score 32):

Add the line to your *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* file or `.profile`.

The variables set in file *$HOME/.profile* are active for the current user, and the ones in `/etc/profile` are global. The *.bashrc* file is pulled on each Bash session start.

Answer (score 7):

If it suits anyone, here are some brief guidelines for adding environment variables permanently.

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the variables to the file:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export JAVA_HOME=~/opt/openjdk11
```

Immediately apply all changes:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Source: *[How to Set Environment Variables in Linux](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/)*

Answer (score 3):

A particular example:

I have Java 7 and Java 6 installed, I need to run some builds with 6, others with 7. Therefore I need to dynamically alter `JAVA_HOME` so that [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) picks up what I want for each build. I did the following:

- created `j6.sh` script which simply does export `JAVA_HOME=...` path to j6 install...
- then, as suggested by one of the comments above, whenever I need J6 for a build, I run source `j6.sh` in that respective command terminal. By default, my `JAVA_HOME` is set to J7.