# Environment path set to "PATH" variable missing after system restart?

Tags: android, linux, unix, path, path-variables

I have set

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

and execute the above line in command line and later if I type echo $PATH, I could see the path added. But after restarting the system I couldn't see it any more. But putting the system to sleep and then starting again, I could still see it. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: it's a shell variable. put it into your shell's `rc` file.You realize that "sleep" is not the same as "reboot"?

Comment: Please clarify as to where (in what file) this line of code occurs.

Comment: I am running the command in unix command line as sudo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding it using export on command line would just set it for the current session.To set it permanently you need to add it to .bashrc or /etc/profile.

Your question is similar to:
[How to permanently export a variable in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux)