# Tk initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: linux

I am trying to invoke the tool on Centos server from the Ubantu terminal.I am getting the following error.

**Tk initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable.**

Please Help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I upgraded `matplotlib-2.2.3` to `matplotlib-3.0.2`, having solved this problem. For a simple test: `import matplotlib;matplotlib.use('TkAgg');import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;plt.plot(range(10))`

Answer (score 9):

Connect to your CentOS machine with `ssh -Y` which (per `man ssh`)

> Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

That will allow your Tk process to connect to X11 on your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I did ssh -Y username@192.***.*** to connect server.I want to run tool.But the GUI mode of the tool is not opening.

Answer (score 7):

I work on Ubuntu. I had the same problem while using gitk on remote machines.
So I tried following

`ssh <username>@ip` and ran `gitk&` got the `"no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable."` error

```
ssh -X <username>@ip and ran gitk& it worked!
ssh -Y <username>@ip and ran gitk& it worked!
```

Thanks for the [solution by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34585087/4298200).

Comment: ssh -x was a perfect solution for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was having same issue using gitk on a new local machine with Ubuntu 21.04 and this solved my problem

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: To start a script with the DISPLAY variable you can also use: ```env -i DISPLAY=:0 command_or_script```

Comment: and for permanent solution, can use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux