# How to set or change the default software path in R

Tags: r

I have a program called "bowtie2" and I changed the default path in terminal:

```
$export PATH=/opt/NGS/bowtie2-2.2.8:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin
$bowtie2 --version
/opt/NGS/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s version 2.2.8
```

But when I call it from R it's still the old version from other path:

```
> bowtie2="bowtie2"
> system2(bowtie2,"--version",stdout=TRUE)[1]
[1] "/usr/bin/bowtie2-align version 2.1.0"
```

My question is how to change the default path for the program in R (so that the version is "/opt/NGS/bowtie2-2.2.8/bowtie2-align-s version 2.2.8" rather "/usr/bin/bowtie2-align version 2.1.0")

Comment: Did u restart R after changing the path? You might want to echo path in R to check also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `export PATH=/opt/NGS/bowtie2-2.2.8:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin` to the end of .bashrc(linux) or .bash_profile(mac) file in your home folder.

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

And then add the export command at the end of the file, otherwise it will only work for your current shell session. When you use `system` command in R, it launches a new shell session, which the `export` command won't apply to.

See [this link to find out more about `export` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux)