# cannot load R package qdap

Tags: java, r

I am using Mac os x el Capitan version 10.11.4
and I got this error while trying to load qdap library .

> JavaVM: Failed to load JVM:
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
>   JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library. Error : .onLoad failed
>   in loadNamespace() for 'openNLPdata', details:   call: .jinit()
>   error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'qdap'

I tried to do this :

step#1 `sudo R CMD javareconf`

step#2 `install.packages("rJava",type='source')`

but I not able to run sudo R CMD javareconf

> sudo: R: command not found

Comment: It's possible that you didn't include the path to `R` as your environment variable. Are you able to simply run `R`?

Comment: how do I add r to my environment ? I tried the full path but I am not sure what is the full path,,, /Applications/RStudio.app -> this is not working for me

Comment: You need to export the path in your `.bash_profile` file. Check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728394/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-software-path-in-r/36731696#36731696.

Comment: but I dont understand what is the full path to R

Comment: Try `/Applications/R.app`.

Comment: Just FYI, `RStudio` is just an IDE, it's not R engine.

Comment: not working :( . I tried to change the path and it still not familier with Rstudio.app

Comment: Are you able to run `R` from the terminal? Normally, you don't have to export the path.