# Sys.getenv() returns empty in Shiny Apps

Tags: r, shiny

*NOTE* *I edited the question, since the use of `PG_HOST` was causing confussion, but the spirit is the same*

I am running a shiny app that needs read some environment variables.

That variables are defined before the shiny server starts. For example

```
export APPLE=apple
export PENCIL=pencil
```

In the `global.R` (or at the beggining of `server.R` is the same) I wrote the following code:

```
manzana <- Sys.getenv('APPLE')
lapiz <- Sys.getenv('PENCIL')
```

but those variables are empty.

If I run that code in the R console, both returns the correct value.

Whay this is not working? Whay is different the R console and the shiny app?
How I can get the real environment variables (in this fake example `$APPLE` and `$PENCIL`)?
Which is the correct way of configuring the shiny app?

Comment: The PATH in your shell is different than the PATH seen by R. Try `system("echo $PG_HOST")` at the R console to see that this is true. Since you know how to use `Sys.getenv`, the way forward should be clear now.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, and effectively, `Sys.getenv` returns very differently in the console and in the shiny app. I am not an expert (obviously), but I don't know how to follow from here. Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: couple of important questions....is the database a cloud db or is it flat file? Does it require auth?  When you deploy a shiny app...the path to your local file system will be invalid...because it's not served from your local machine. There are workarounds...ie update your db locally and then push new db to a cloud file that is called from your app.

Comment: You should really just read this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/libpq-envars.html

Comment: @CarlBoneri thank you for your answer, but the problem is that shiny is not reading the environment variables as expected. Any environment variable.

Comment: If you wanted to change the value of PATH that you were getting from `Sys,getenv` then I thought that using `Sys.setenv` was the obvious next step. If you were going to make the new location first on the search path then it would be something along the lines of `Sys.setenv( PATH=paste( "<whatever echo $PG_HOST returned in your Terminal session>", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":") )`. Cannot give much in the way of tested code since you have offered virtually no specifics.

Comment: @42- I edited the question. I cannot use the value in the terminal for editing the code in the shiny app, I want to dinamically read the environment variables.

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you find a solution. I want to read environment variables because they are used to store the connection strings to a database.

Answer (score 0):

For those who, like me, are finding this question years later, the secret of getting this to work depends on two things:

- Setting the environment variable [permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13046663/10744082)
- Making it available to the user `shiny` on the server computer

So, for example, the app:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1(paste("Run by", Sys.getenv("USER"))),
  textInput("name", "What is your name?", value = "Friendly User"),
  actionButton("greet", "Greet"),
  textOutput("greeting")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$greeting <- renderText({
    req(input$greet)
    paste0(Sys.getenv("greeting"), " ", isolate(input$name), "!")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Run after the command `export greeting='Hello'` should say "Hello Friendly User!" if it's finding the correct environment variable, but:

[image]

The `export` statement only sets the environment variable for that session (when you have the terminal open). Even with `shiny` as user, the session you set the variable in will differ from the session the server is running (which, I think, is constant whilst the server is up). However, see that `Sys.getenv("USER")` is *correctly* discovering the system environment variable specifying that the user running the server is `shiny`.

There are a [number of ways](https://docs.posit.co/shiny-server/#environment-variable-settings) of setting environment variables for a shiny server, most of which would require the restarting of the server after running the command (not always possible). If you set it in `/etc/environment` then it should allow all users (including `shiny`) to access it whenever it's requested without requiring a restart:

`echo greeting='Hello' >> /etc/environment`

gives:

[image]

For further details, and to try out various options, [here's a docker image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/andybaxter/setting_server_envs) of the above app, created from [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/andrewbaxter439/test_shinytests/blob/main/Dockerfile) which runs the setting environment variable command.

Answer (score -1):

First step is to understand reactivity. Check out the shiny tutorials.

using your example..kind of..heres an app the updates and sets variables that can be called numerous ways....

```
shiny_example <- function(){

  server <- shinyServer(function(session,input,output){
    the_slots <- list(Apple = 'apple',Green = 'green')

    make_globs <- function(new_var = NULL){
      if(!is.null(new_var)){
        the_slots <<- append(the_slots,new_var)
      }
    }

    glob_vals <- the_slots

    glob_vals <- eventReactive(input$saver, {
      set_new_vars <- list(input$new_var)
      names(set_new_vars) <- input$new_var_name
      the_slots <<- make_globs(new_var = set_new_vars)
      lapply(list('new_var','new_var_name'),function(i)updateTextInput(session,i, value = ""))
      return(the_slots)

    })

    output$envs <- renderPrint({

      glob_vals()

    })

    output$sels <- renderUI({
      vals <- 1:length(glob_vals())
      Opts <- unlist(lapply(vals,function(i)sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>',i,names(glob_vals()[i])))) %>% HTML
      HTML(
        paste(
          "<div class='shiny-input-container'>",
          "<label class='control-label' for='the_ups'></label>",
          "<div><select id='the_ups'>",Opts,"</select></div>",
          "</div>",sep=""))
    })

    output$sel_vals <- renderPrint({
      ref_cards <- lapply(1:length(glob_vals()),function(i)
        data.frame(the_names = names(glob_vals()[i]),the_vals = glob_vals()[[i]]))%>%
        rbind.pages

      ref_cards[input$the_ups,'the_vals']


    })

  })


  ui <- shinyUI(
    bootstrapPage(
      tags$div(class="container",
               fluidRow(
                 tags$h4(HTML('These inputs will update the variable list \n like a variable in Sys.getenv()')),
                 column(6,textInput(inputId = "new_var_name",label = "variable name")),
                 column(6,textInput(inputId = "new_var",label = 'variable value'))
               ),
               fluidRow(

                 column(6,
                        tags$h4(
                          HTML('Pressing the `add_new` button will load the variables and display the corresponding values below'),
                          actionButton(inputId = "saver",label = "add_new")
                        )),
                 column(6,tags$h4("You can even dynamically update a selection input with newly created paths or environment variables"),
                        uiOutput('sels'))
               ),
               fluidRow(
                 column(6,verbatimTextOutput('envs')),
                 column(6,verbatimTextOutput('sel_vals')))
      )))

  shinyApp(ui,server)

}
```

And the result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you again, but I really  want to read a variable from the environment with `Sys.getenv` ...

Comment: Can I ask why? Sys.getenv is a function that plucks a named variable from a stored list... But anyways, best of luck

Comment: I don't want to hardcode  some information  (like passwords, urls, ports etc.) So i though that I could read it from the environment variables. That's  what Sys.getenv does