# Symfony keeps switching to dev

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony app, which I pushed to production server according to the Smyfony Help Page [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html).

I have a command cronjob, that parses the logfiles by the enviroment, like this:

```
$env = $this->getContainer()->getParameter("kernel.environment");

    /* Read Logfile */
    $fs = new Filesystem();
    if ($fs->exists(Constants::LOG_PATH . '/'.$env.'_error-' . $yesterday->format('Y-m-d') . '.log')) {
     ...
   }else{
     /*Send mail for fail */
   }
```

When I do `export SYMFONY_ENV=prod` and run the command manually, it works. At night it fails because the `dev` log does not exist. I also added the `export SYMFONY_ENV=prod` to `~/.bashrc` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31546962/1092632), still no luck.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use

Answer (score 0):

You can add the env to your cron like:

```
*/30 * * * * SYMFONY_ENV=prod php /usr/share/nginx/html/test/bin/console cache:clear
```