# How to Auth to Google Cloud using Service Account in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, oauth-2.0, service-accounts

I'm trying to make a project that will upload Google Storage JSON file to BigQuery (just automate something that is done manually now), and I'd like to use a 'service account' for this as my script is going to be run on daily basis.

After reading everything I can found about using service account, I'm still struggling to authenticate.

Here is what i've done so far:

1. Created JSON key file for service account
2. Installed client libraries: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`
3. Installed Google Cloud SDK according to: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/
4. Run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>` with key path specified correctly

Now I'm trying to run the following python script:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
```

But I get this error:

> `google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError`: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` or
> explicitly create credential and re-run the application. For more
> information, please see
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.

I'm quite new to both Python and the Google Cloud API so possbily missed something. Can someone point out where/what was wrong in my steps above or point me to clear instruction for dummys about setting up and running simple script with BigQuery using service account?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I usually set this variable in the python script itself, something like:

```
import os
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path_to_json_file'
bq_client = Client()
```

Comment: setting the credentials locally and running the script works. But when I am creating a docker image for the script it shows that JSON file is not there! How do I add service JSON file to the docker  image

Comment: @Madhi I recommend asking this question on SO explaining what you are trying to do (I imagine this is something related to not properly adding the file in the build docker process but more information is needed in your case)

Comment: Thanks for the reply comment. I figured out the solution and everything is working fine inside a docker image. Thanks!

Comment: @Madhi please post your solutions for others to see

Answer (score 41):

If you have implemented more fine-grained control over service accounts permissions and you have an app that needs to use several of them (say one for Pub/Sub, one for storage), then you would have to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable before creating each client.

Instead, you can load your credentials separately and pass them to their appropriate clients like so:

```py
import json
    
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
    
project_id = 'my-test-project'
    
with open('/path/to/my/service_keys/storage_service.json') as source:
    info = json.load(source)

storage_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(info)
    
storage_client = storage.Client(project=project_id, credentials=storage_credentials)
```

Just make sure in your IAM console that the account has the right permissions to perform the operations you need it to do, but luckily in that case the error messages are really informative.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post, but I just had a quick question, as I am stuck with setting up my service account. Is it a case that once you set your key, you download it and store it where you want it? or there is a way to find the location as to where this is stored? this is where I am confused. Need to paste path of service.json in my python file that I downloaded to run a dataflow pipeline.

Comment: @mowem10 You can always download the key again from GCP and then move it to where the script can find it 

Answer (score 16):

Are you running the script in the same command line session as the one you set your environment variable in using export? If not, you might want to look into setting it for your user or system (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux) for more info).

Another option that might make things even easier and takes care of these things automatically is using the [gcloud cli tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/). If you look at the second option [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) under the *How the Application Default Credentials* work, you can find info on how to use it to manage the credentials for you (`gcloud auth login` and `gcloud auth application-default login`)

Comment: In my case, the `gcloud auth application-default login` command was the right (and non-obvious) solution. Thanks!

Comment: This `gcloud auth application-default login` requirement was so hard to find!

Answer (score 7):

I simply set credentials as a variable in python code, not a good idea to show credentials directly in python code though :)

```
#!pip install google-api-python-client
#!pip install google-cloud-dns

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.cloud import dns


#Downloaded credentials in JSON format
gcp_sa_credentials={
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "mygcpprojectid-1122",
  "private_key_id": "myprivkeyid",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nmyprivatekey\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "client-mail@mygcpprojectid-1122.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "myclientid",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/client-mail%40mygcpprojectid-1122.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

project_id=gcp_sa_credentials["project_id"]

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcp_sa_credentials)
client = dns.Client(project=project_id,credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: `dns` is not defined. We need `pip install google-cloud-storage` then `from google.cloud import storage as dns`

Comment: @mountrix , I  have specified callling `dns.Client()` now, can be managed through `pip install google-cloud-dns` then `from google.cloud import dns`

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question however I want to add that you *must* create a **new** service account and not use an old one. A recent Google Cloud Next presentation on security stated that there is *no guarantee* that the default service account will exist in future, and it could be removed at any time (or its available permissions changed), so none of your applications should depend on it. Also I've found that there are potential issues with authentication when using the default service account and creating a new one is more likely to allow the control you need to successfully authenticate.

Refer to the following YouTube presentation from 11mins 10s in:

https://youtu.be/ZQHoC0cR6Qw?t=670