# Google cloud Natural Language API error:google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-natural-language

**I use Google cloud's Natural Language API from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python):**

**And I use this command in powershell :**

> $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="D:\analyze_sentiment\MyFirstProject-bbe4f7bccb98.json"

[image]

**Then I use this command in cmd:**

> set
> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=D:\analyze_sentiment\MyFirstProject-bbe4f7bccb98.json

[image]

**But when I use python code:**

```
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types

# Instantiates a client
client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
# The text to analyze
text = u'Hello, world!'
document = types.Document(
    content=text,
    type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
# Detects the sentiment of the text
sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment
print('Text: {}'.format(text))
print('Sentiment: {}, {}'.format(sentiment.score, sentiment.magnitude))
```

**The error message said:**

> raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
> google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not
> automatically determine credentials. Please set
> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and
> re-run the application. For more information, please see
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.

**Why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the error reason,I must use cmd mode to run the code,please do not run the code with pycharm or other IDE.And set this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/language.googleapis.com/) API "enable".

And then the error disappeared.

Comment: If you still want to use Pycharm or other IDE, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328277/how-to-auth-to-google-cloud-using-service-account-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS also in you local machine. Download Google Cloud Shell and set there the credentials

Comment: I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in powershell and cmd.But I run my code with pycharm.When I use cmd to run the code,it does not have this mistake.But every time I get into the cmd, I have to set it once.Is there any way to set it up once? I don't want to set it  every time.