# Can I use another credential methods in python script except for service account?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-authentication

I was trying [this pub/sub client tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries), and got this error in `publisher.py`

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

when I call this part.

```py
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
```

I am a member of a GCP group which has already pubsub.publisher, pubsub.subscriber roles.
And I registered my account on my local machine.
So, if I use CLI command on terminal like

```sh
gcloud pubsub topics publish <topic-name> --message="help me"
```

It succeeds.

I can see that python script can be seen as a service, so it needs service account. But is there any way to use my group's credentials in python script too, or should I use a service account?

---

(12.03.2021 updated 1)
Thanks for answering guys, (Sorry, I'm noob in GCP).
I have no roles to give specific roles to a service account, which means that I cannot make a service account that has roles pubsub.publisher and pubsub.subscriber. (this is our department's policy. is it kind of wired??) So for the tutorials in local machine, I just want to use groups IAM (user account IAM) for a credentials. Is there no way not to use service account?? (I just thought that there is a way even though python script can be seen as a service)

---

(12.03.2021 updated 2)

`gcloud auth application-default login` worked as suggested by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329070/13132411)

Comment: you may want to take a look at this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328277/how-to-auth-to-google-cloud-using-service-account-in-python

Comment: @lukaszberwid Thanks, I applied `gcloud auth application-default login` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Add your service account email in your Google Groups and Voilà!

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have no roles to give specific roles to a service account, which means that I cannot make a service account that has roles pubsub.publisher and pubsub.subscriber. Is there no way not to use service account?  (I updated my question)

Comment: You can avoid to use a service account in your local environment and use your own credential. But, when your app run on Google Cloud, you can't (in fact I prefer not to say how to achieve that hack and very bad practice) use your own credential, you will have to use a service account.