# How to set Go environment variables globally

Tags: bash, go, environment-variables

when I declare my Go environment (namely GOPATH and GOROOT using simple export):

```
export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.9/
export GOPATH=/my/workspace/go
```

The current terminal recognizes the variables normally, but if I open another terminal window, these variables are not set and they need to be reconfigured from scratch.

Is there a go-specific way to set default values for go environment variables other than common ways like editing the .bashrc file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently export a variable in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux)

Comment: why was this quesiton put on hold? It is a valid question on how to make environment variables permanant. This is not a question limited to Super User since it is a daily task for developers also.

Comment: I know how to make variables permanent and setting the path. The problem is Go variables do not seem to persist whatever I do.

Comment: Actually, you can run `$ go env -w GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.9/` theses days to make the value permanent. I think this question would be useful since it is the best way to set the go environment

Comment: If you think this is a good question you should vote it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) you just need to include exports 
`export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.9/`
`export GOPATH=/my/workspace/go`
at the bottom of the file ~/.profile in your home directory

Comment: I did that but the change did not persist for new terminals.

Comment: Try adding those two lines also at the bottom of ~/.bashrc