# Can't Set NODE_ENV to "production" in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux

I'm trying to set the NODE_ENV variable and other ones in the production environment.

When I log in and do:

```
$ export NODE_ENV=production
```

It works. I can then check the variable with:

```
$ echo $NODE_ENV
```

The result is "production"

**But if I log out and log in again the variable is empty**, why is this
happening? How can I set the environment variables persistently?

Comment: You would need to set it in your shell profile. think `.bashrc` or `.profile` all depending on your system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently export a variable in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux)