# ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gifski’

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rust, centos

I'd like to use the `gganimate` package, but it requires `gifski` which is failing.

```
* installing *source* package ‘gifski’ ...
** package ‘gifski’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
------------------ RUST COMPILER NOT FOUND --------------------

Cargo was not found on the PATH. Please install cargo / rustc:

 - yum install cargo         (Fedora/CentOS)
 - apt-get install cargo     (Debian/Ubuntu)
 - brew install rustc        (MacOS)

Alternatively install Rust from: <https://www.rust-lang.org>

---------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gifski’
* removing ‘/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/gifski’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gifski’ had non-zero exit status
```

It says I need to install Rust, but I've done that. I ran these commands and then rebooted.

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

I'm on a CentOS Linux machine hosted on EC2.

Comment: This is an **exact duplicate** of [Rust compiler not found when installing gifski](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55769591/155423)

Comment: Any recommendations to connect the compiler?

Answer (score -1):

If you're in linux Ubuntu, first install rust compiler:

terminal > sudo apt-get install cargo

then, install gifski from github:
devtool::install_github("r-rust/gifski")

or using remotes package:
remotes::install_github("r-rust/gifski")

i hope i helped you.

Comment: OP said they were on CentOS (Red Hat derivative, yum-based), so an Ubuntu-focused solution might not help them.