# How to permanently set GOPATH environmental variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I set `GOPATH` as an environment variable on my **Ubuntu** VM as the following: `export GOPATH="/go"` and it works fine.

The problem is, after I reboot my machine `GOPATH` is no longer an environment variable.

[How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix), but in my case I need to set an environment variable and not path.

Why is that and how can I set it permanently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux-unix)

Comment: Duplicate of: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)

Comment: I edited my question. I don't think I'm duplicating the question

Comment: You have to just paste the command you are manually typing on the terminal at the end of the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently export a variable in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Edit (or create) `~/.bashrc` and add the line there.  That's assuming that you have stuck to the defaults and not chosen a different shell.