# how can i persist environment variables in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am in production environment on a vps that has linux. I have a file where I try to set my environment variables.
my variables are in a file called `environment.js`.

the content of my file is like this:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "prod";
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
process.env.SEED = "seed";
console.log(process.env.SEED);
process.env.SEED_PORTAL = "seed_bee"
console.log(process.env.SEED_PORTAL);
process.env.HOST = "http://3.86.232.97";
```

then I run

```
node environment.js
```

and I would expect the values to persist, but these variables are not global, they appear as undefined where I try to use them in other projects where I use nodejs

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set environment variables manually in node they only persist to that instance of node, since you're setting them in memory and not on the disk. If you're looking to share them across processes, one way is to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) as Iggnaxios pointed out, in all of the applications, and have the same variables in each application's `.env` file, or have them all use the same `.env` file.

Node will also pull environment variables from your operating system. See [How to permanently export a variable in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux) on how to set environment variables in Linux

Answer (score -2):

to work with environment variables you must install the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) library

Answer (score -2):

I created a single-purpose *CLI* tool that does what you want in 1 line if you put your key/value pairs in a *YAML* file. See [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-env-cli) & [GitHub](https://github.com/whyboris/YAML-env-CLI)

Install:

```
npm install -g yaml-env-cli
```

Now you can run:

```
export `yec my_env_file.yaml` && node index.js
```

Anything after `&&` is the script / command you want to run. Under the hood, the `yec` *CLI* simply reads any `.yaml` file you give it and outputs it as a string, formatted for the `export` command to work.