# How can I set a global variable of a Linux process from another process?

Tags: c, linux

I'm creating a fault injection framework, and would like to do something like:

```
volatile bool doFaultWriteError;
```

In my code, I can then check the global variable to decide whether to do the fault.

In BSD, I hear you can teach sysctl to set variable in user space processes.  Is this possible in Linux?  How do I do it?

My current plan is to have a SIGHUP handler that read a "fault configuration" file and then sets globals as appropriate.  But if there's already something in Linux that can do this, that would be simpler.

Comment: Programming language? http://www.makelinux.net/alp/035

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `mmap` to share a page via a file handler (shm_open) then communicate between two applications.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change the environment of another process, and I would be surprised if you could do that in any UNIX system.

There are some hacks described in this other question: [Is there a way to change another process's environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables) but they are just ugly hacks :)

Comment: The question is to change a _global variable_ in the process-space, and not an environment variable per-se.

Comment: Debuggers and dtrace/systemtap let you modify state of another process, so the hooks are there.