# python os.environ variable do not pass in the bash script

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I have a python script (using a pseudo-terminal) to pass an environment variable called "CDP":

```
def download(self, dPluzz, donnees=None):        # to call the bash script
    self.child_pid = self.v.fork_command(None, ['/bin/bash', 'dPluzz-cli', '-f', dest, '-u', adresse])   
    os.environ["CDP"] = "False"                  # set cancel as "False"
def cancel(self, dPluzz, donnees=None):
    if self.annul == 0:
      if self.time > 10 and self.percent != 100:
         os.environ["CDP"] = "True"
         print os.environ["CDP"]                 # returns True
         self.child_pid = str(self.child_pid)
         cmd = 'kill -TERM' + " " + self.child_pid
         subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
def __init__(self):                              #Pseudo-Terminal in GTK window     
      self.v = vte.Terminal()                    #(displayed in a notebook)
      self.v.connect ("child-exited", lambda term: self.verif(self, a))
      self.v.connect('contents-changed', self.term)
      self.v.set_size(70,20)
      self.v.set_encoding("UTF-8")  
      self.v.set_cursor_blinks(False) 
      self.v.show()
      self.page.add(self.v)
```

The bash script is:

```
kill_jobs()
{
    pkill -TERM -P "$BASHPID"
    echo -e "$CDP"                                # returns False, should be True
    if [ "$CDP" == "True" ]; then
    echo -e "OPERATIONS ANNULEES"
    elif [ "$CDP" == "False" ]; then
    echo -e "OPERATIONS TERMINEES"
    fi
}
```

The problem is, `$CDP = False` so the message displayed is not good.
What is the reason?
Thanks

Comment: how is CDB set to string "False" if you didn't set it?

Comment: it is very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve here :(

Comment: I understand. The "False" is set when the script bash is called. I will edit my question later, I must go eat... Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

After setting the environment via

```
os.environ["CDP"] = "True"
```

You can get this value in you bash only if you call the bash script via `os.system(), os.popen() or os.fork() and os.execv().`

so If you can add

```
os.system('/bin/bash script.sh')
```

You shall be able to use the value of CDP in bash script normally.

Please read [`os.putenv()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=putenv#os.putenv)

I guess os.environ and os.putenv() are closely related.

Comment: @Guillaume +1 for Your question, it helped me understand the os.* even more.

Comment: I don't understand, because the shell script is already running when I try to cancel it

Comment: Please elaborate, can not guess what you meant.
I am saying, you shall get `CDP` value in bash script only if you fire the script using `os.system()` or any of the methods I have mentioned above, If shell script is running and then you are running python program and thinking that `CDP` can be read as True then its not possible. Please kill both python and shell script now and make changes as I suggested and then look for the expected results.