# Can't clear Laravel cache when using multiple Docker containers

Tags: laravel, docker

I am unable to refresh the Laravel cache and I think the problem could be related to using multiple Docker containers running the Laravel stack. I've tried `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`. I've deleted `bootstrap/cache/config.php` but the file just reappears with the old config like some undead creature haunting me.

The only way I am able to get the cache to refresh is by completely removing containers with `docker-compose down` and then running the containers again.

In my docker-compose below you can see that my app, queue and scheduler containers all run the Laravel stack with the codebase mounted from the host. Could this be contributing to the problem?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    env_file: '.env'
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      #APP_ENV: local
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      - ./php/opcache.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  scheduler:
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: scheduler
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    env_file: '.env'
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: scheduler
    networks:
      - app-network

  queue:
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: queue
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./supervisor/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
      - ./supervisor/conf.d:/etc/supervisor/conf.d
    env_file: '.env'
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: queue
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${local_ip}:${host_web_port}:80"
      #- "${local_ip}:443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.26
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${local_ip}:${host_db_port}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

**Can somebody tell me how I can reload the cache without the need to destroy the containers?**

For the sake of completeness, I set up the Docker environment using this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose

I am running the queue and scheduler containers using this guide: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-scheduler-queue-docker . However I've modified the queue to run Supervisor.

start.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

role=${CONTAINER_ROLE:-app}
env=${APP_ENV:-production}

if [ "$env" != "local" ]; then
    echo "Caching configuration..."
    (php artisan config:cache && php artisan view:cache) # && php artisan route:cache - can't cache route closures
fi

if [ "$role" = "app" ]; then

    exec php-fpm

elif [ "$role" = "queue" ]; then

    echo "Running the queue..."
    /usr/bin/supervisord

elif [ "$role" = "scheduler" ]; then

    while [ true ]
    do
      php artisan schedule:run --verbose --no-interaction &
      sleep 60
    done

else
    echo "Could not match the container role \"$role\""
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Did you also try `php artisan optimize:clear`?

Comment: I have not tried that because I have some routes that use closures, which break `php artisan optimize`. But for the sake of trying everything, I'll replace the closures with controllers and try it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* I now understand what is happening to me. My Laravel config options are defined by a `.env` file which my `docker-compose.yml` file is also reading to set the container environment variables. These [container environment variables cannot be changed at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41350528/1039690), and always take precedence over changes made to the `.env` file while the containers are running.

Stopping and starting the container does not change the environment variables. Only by destroying the container and getting it to start again, thereby re-reading the `.env` file to set environment variables, do my changes take effect.

The proper set up then should be to use `.env` for Laravel only, and a separate file for container environment variables. In other words, change the `env_file: '.env'` entry in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Hello
I'm in the same case. Working with stripe webhooks and laravel jobs I need to `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` every time I change the code in one of my job.
I don't understand what is doing the .env used commonly between docker&&Laravel in the problem. If you could explain I would appreciate :)

Comment: I think "job" is they key word in your question. I have also found that Laravel jobs are notoriously difficult to keep in sync with code changes. I need to completely kill the job container for changes to take effect. This is easier when using a separate container just for jobs. Sorry I can't offer more specific knowledge.

Comment: This is actually a very useful answer. I was trying for 2 hours. It makes sense to put only the required env vars to docker context (e.g. using env_file) and not everything from projects env file.