# How to increase the server timeout on the fly

Tags: go, server

In PHP we have `ini_set('max_execution_time', 180)` by which we can change the execution time on the fly.
Is there anything similar to this in Go?

Comment: No, there's not. It wouldn't really make sense in Go, either, since Go isn't single-threaded like PHP.

Comment: The only similar timeouts Go offers are the various Timeouts in the [`http.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) struct. And they can only be set on startup (although you could construct a program that would re-start a server when config changes, without restarting the whole process--but probably not worth it)

Comment: A more dynamic approach would be to set a context timeout (perhaps in middleware) per connection. That could easily be done without restarting, but would only affect new connections.

Comment: The context approach as suggested by @Flimzy is how I go about it. I have a `middleware` per se, which calls `context.WithTimeout` to create a new context. To make it dynamic, you can pick the value from an env variable to avoid restarting

Comment: @AyushGupta: You cannot reset an ENV variable without restarting, though.

Comment: @Flimzy oh is that? Then maybe another mechanism. Personally I would want(expect, perhaps) to pick the latest env variable value, but I guess caching that makes sense too(I believe it's cached at a shell level). Good to know, thanks

Comment: @AyushGupta: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/205064/13860 TL;DR; There are hacky ways to change an env variable while the process is running, but there's no standard way to tell the process to re-read the env variables, so in practice, it's impossible. (And I'm sure the Go runtime doesn't support it, so you'd be stuck doing some low-level system calls to re-read the env)

Answer (score 0):

Heres a script that allows you to set a program timeout and dynamically change timeout during execution.
https://play.golang.org/p/qRvVMPnp9g2

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "os"
)

var (
    oldDuration time.Duration = 10 * time.Second
    timer *time.Timer = time.NewTimer(oldDuration)
    start time.Time = time.Now()
)

// The init function is called before main
func init(){
    // function asynchronously monitors and terminates script after timeout
    go func(){
        <- timer.C
        fmt.Println("Exit")
        os.Exit(1)
    }()
}

func main() {

    // Do some work
    <-time.After(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Hello World")

    // Change timeout interval dynamically
    setTimeout(5 * time.Second)

    // Do more work
    <-time.After(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Shouldn't be reached as script terminates after 5 seconds of which 2 seconds have been used earlier")
}

func setTimeout(newDuration time.Duration){

     // Stop timer - prevent program terminating in setTimeout function
     timer.Stop()

     // Compute remaining time
     var timePassed time.Duration = time.Since(start)
     var timeToTermination time.Duration = newDuration - timePassed

     // Restart timer - continuing from however many second 
     // have elapsed since the program started
     oldDuration = newDuration
     timer.Reset(timeToTermination)
}
```